# how to create a simple web form in scala/lift

Tags: forms, scala, lift

I need to create a from in lift with username and phone number.
can someone give a full example how to create a simple form in lift that can be submitted? or a reference to a good one. all examples I have seen are not full or has too many options for me, and I couldn't manage to compile them.
Thanks,
Ohad.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find an excellent, simple example in the introductory course given by David Pollak in London [here](http://github.com/dpp/lift_training_london/). The snippet for the simple form (instead of a phone number as you comment it has an age) is [here](http://github.com/dpp/lift_training_london/blob/master/src/main/scala/code/snippet/SimpleForm.scala). The html associated is [this one](http://github.com/dpp/lift_training_london/blob/master/src/main/webapp/form.html), just comment the Lift Screen section and uncomment the simple form.

Please also note that Lift has a very active and willing to help community, so you can also ask these questions in the [Lift mail list](http://groups.google.com/group/liftweb).